# Sort array by specific order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array

```
peeps = [{name: "Mike", age: 31},{name: "Dave", age: 31},{name: "Delta", age: 31},{name: "Clint", age: 31}]
```

And I need to sort them by an arbitrary order of

```
newOrder = ['Delta', 'Dave', 'Mike', 'Clint']
```

How would I reference `newOrder` to sort `peeps`, also bear in mind the data in `peeps` is not guaranteed to have all the names in `newOrder`

Comment: please add your code. what have you tried?

Comment: The name will be known, newOrder will be static but peeps might have all the names or only 1 of the names in peeps. I've tried to figure out a way to do it by sorting alphabetically and then reversing the order but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const peeps = [
  { name: 'Mike', age: 31 },
  { name: 'Dave', age: 31 },
  { name: 'Delta', age: 31 },
  { name: 'Clint', age: 31 }
];
const newOrder = ['Delta', 'Dave', 'Mike', 'Clint'];

peeps.sort((a, b) => newOrder.indexOf(a.name) - newOrder.indexOf(b.name));

console.log(peeps);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```js
const peeps = [{name: "Mike", age: 31},{name: "Dave", age: 31},{name: "Delta", age: 31},{name: "Clint", age: 31}];
const newOrder = ['Delta', 'Dave', 'Mike', 'Clint'];

const notInNewOrder = peeps.filter(i => !newOrder.includes(i.name));

const response = newOrder.map(n => ({...peeps.find(peep=> peep.name === n)}));

console.log(response.concat(notInNewOrder));
```